# Struggling with R environments and evaluating expressions

Tags: r

I need to parse and evaluate an expression inside a function. If I do
both tasks from primitive functions 'eval' and 'parse', the interpretation
seem to work ok:

```
ff0 <- function() {
  aaa <- 5
  ss <- "aaa"
  print(eval(parse(text = ss)))
}

> ff0()
[1] 5
```

However, if I try to encapsulate both functions into a single function,
as follows:

```
evalstr <- function(s, ...) eval(parse(text=s), ...)

ff1 <- function() {
  aaa <- 5
  ss <- "aaa"
  print(evalstr(ss))
}

> ff1()
 Error in eval(parse(text = s), ...) : 'aaa' object not found
```

The code does not work as expected. I think an environment ought to be passed to 'eval', but I don't know which one.

Comment: Maybe specify the `envir`.  Also, you may use `get`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the following solution. I removed `...` as I didn't understand what you where trying to pass to `eval` with it.

```
library(rlang)

evalstr <- function(s) eval_tidy(parse_expr(s), env = caller_env())

ff1 <- function() {
  aaa <- 5
  ss <- "aaa"
  print(evalstr(ss))
}

ff1()
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify the `envir`.  This would be more compact with `get`

```
ff0 <- function() {
  aaa <- 5
  ss <- "aaa"
  print(get(ss))
}

ff0()
[1] 5
evalstr <- function(s, envir = parent.frame()) get(s, envir = envir)

ff1 <- function() {
  aaa <- 5
  ss <- "aaa"
  print(evalstr(ss))
}
ff1()
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the target expression is not as simple as the posted one, I'm modifying  ff0, ff1 functions as well as giving an answer based on the one posted by [https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun][1]:

```
ff0 <- function() {
  aaa <- 5
  bbb <- 4
  ss <- "aaa+bbb"
  print(eval(parse(text = ss)))
}

evalstr <- function(s, ...) eval(parse(text=s), envir = parent.frame(), ...)

ff1 <- function() {
  aaa <- 5
  bbb <- 4
  ss <- "aaa+bbb"
  print(evalstr(ss))
}
```

In this case 'get' does not work.